# Square root of the wave operator

Tags: dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation, dirac-matrices

How are the Dirac matrices the square root of the wave operator? I keep seeing it mentioned as such but never explained.

Comment: Sources/References?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are confusing the Dirac matrices ($\gamma^\mu$)
with the [Dirac operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_operator) ($\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu$).

You probably mean this: the square of $\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu$
(the Dirac operator) is the [d'Alembert wave operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator) $\square$.

$$(\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu)(\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu)
=\underbrace{\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu}_{=\square}$$
where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric.
This is true because of the [commutator relations of the $\gamma$ matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Mathematical_structure)
$$\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=2\eta^{\mu\nu}$$

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac operator is

$$D=\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\tag{1}$$

Where $\gamma^\mu$ are matrices obeying the Clifford algebra

$$\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}.\tag{2}$$

As such we have that

$$D^2=(\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu)(\gamma^\nu\partial_\nu)=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=\gamma^{(\mu}\gamma^{\nu)}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu=\Box,\tag{3}$$

where in the third equality we used that $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu$ is symmetric and in the fourth equality we used the Clifford algebra. These calculations show that $D^2=\Box$, as such we can think of the Dirac operator as a kind of square root of the Laplace operator.

Comment: " as a kind of square root of the Laplace operator" did you mean  the d'Alembert wave operator?

Comment: In differential geometry is common to call the operator $\Box$ in some semi-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ Laplace-Beltrami operator, or more shortly just Laplace operator, independently of the underlying metric signature (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace-Beltrami_operator). Indeed in Lorentzian signature it can also be called d'Alembert operator.